# Custom QOpenGLWidget and GLEW include

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qtwidgets

Sorry if this is a very basic question, but I'm confused:
I'm using Visual Studio and I'm creating a custom `QOpenGLWidget` class (by inheriting from the base class), and my problem is as follows:

- If I add `#include <QOpenGLWidget>` in my custom class, and also add the `#include` for `glew.h`, I can access the things defined in `glew.h`
- But If I add `#include <QtWidgets>` in my custom class (which I though would cover `QOpenGLWidget` too), then I can't access what is defined in `glew.h` and I see "identifier not defined" errors (for example, for `glGenVertexArrays`)

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here? I'm guessing that including what I only need (`#include <QOpenGLWidget>`) is better than a whole lot of stuff in `<QtWidgets>`, but why should it prevent me from accessing what is defined in `glew.h`?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Note that `#include <QtWidgets>` implies a `#include <QtGui>`, which in turn does a `#include <qopengl.h>`, which in turn includes some OpenGL headers. Maybe `glew.h` has some `#ifndef` protection that gets triggered by that.

Comment: Btw, are you sure you need GLEW?

Comment: @peppe I think I need GLEW because I'm calling direct OpenGL API functions, and I'm not using the wrappers in Qt. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just that you could use the direct wrappers in Qt :-)

Comment: @peppe: Except he can't, since they don't wrap everything. They provide a common OpenGL ES 2 interface, not full desktop GL.

Comment: ? They *do* provide full desktop GL. You've got per-version resolvers (like [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions-3-3-core.html) for 3.3 core) and per-extension (see `QOpenGLExtensions`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simultaneously include Qt's OpenGL wrappers *and* most [OpenGL loading library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) headers. Different .cpp files can include different headers, but the same .cpp cannot. So you're going to have to pick what you want to use: GLEW or Qt's OpenGL wrapper.

The reason this doesn't work is because loaders generally use include guards that prevent you from accidentally including `<GL/gl.h>` or similar headers. Loading libraries tend to be exclusive, since they are often defining the same symbols that other OpenGL headers would. And if they didn't keep you from doing that, you could get multiply-defined-symbol errors if you try to include both.

Qt's OpenGL wrapper is itself a loading library. So it does the same exclusion trick, defining the include guards that GLEW and other loaders would use. As such, you can't use both in the same .cpp file.